Off-ball/on-ball vs off-the-ball/on-the-ball. Which versions are correct as adjectives?
In football (soccer), the expression "on the ball" or "off the ball" is often used to indicate whether a player is possessing or not possessing the ball. It is also often used as an adjective, e.g., off-the-ball movement, on-the-ball event, etc. However, I have encountered that sometimes shorter "off-ball" or "on-ball" expressions are used as adjectives. Therefore, I wonder if there are some strict rules behind the presence (or absence) of "the" within the compound adjective. 1. Is it only brevity that favours shorter versions sometimes? 2. Is one more popular over the other? 3. Does it depend on the formality of the text? Especially, should one be favoured over another for academic writing?

Phrase-finder addresses 'on the ball' as a fixed phrase, often used metaphorically. Searches for 'on ball' usually redirect to 'on the ball', though the 'on ball' at snooker is the one the player must hit next with the cue ball. 'Off the ball' refers to movement / activity on the field of play but away from where the ball actually is at that time. Versions omitting the definite article (eg 'off-ball' for 'off-the-ball' are headlinese.

While off-the-ball seems more common, off-ball is neater as an adjective than off-the-ball; it's licensed by similar forms like off-pitch (and more distantly off-stage, off-piste, off-message, etc).  There's definitely no strict rule about this. As for academic writing, you should be doing a literature search, so have you not drawn any conclusions from that?

@StuartF Literature Search is exactly what got me thinking - while I've encountered both versions, shorter versions seem to be slightly preferred, contrary to general usage (press/books etc.). Warning: the given statement reflects my personal experience only


Therefore, I wonder if there are some strict rules behind the presence (or absence) of "the" within the compound adjective.

There are no "rules" in English: there is guidance.


Is it only brevity that favours shorter versions sometimes?


Yes, that and the choice of the speaker.


Is one more popular over than the other?


Compare them on Google Ngrams, but popularity does not equal being "idiomatic", "natural" or "appropriate."


Does it depend on the formality of the text?


On/Off-the ball is slightly more formal but does not really reach the criteria for "formality."

Especially, should one be favoured over another for academic writing?

You will have to provide an example of "academic" context.

Thanks for hinting Google Ngrams. For the others, this is the result of the query for all English texts:
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=off-the-ball%2Con-the-ball%2Coff-ball%2Con-ball&year_start=2000&year_end=2022&corpus=en&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true. Interestingly, the shorter versions seem to be recently preferred in American English: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=off-the-ball%2Con-the-ball%2Coff-ball%2Con-ball&year_start=2000&year_end=2022&corpus=en-US&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true - possibly this explains the preference for them in academic texts
